Outlook copied calendar event not visible and disappears upon accepting
Copied calendar events in Outlook that were created via a "move" rule are not visible in a shared calendar and disappear upon accepting.
Detailed scenario:
I have two calendars "Personal" and "Work" linked to two email accounts "personal@outlook.com" and "work@work.com". I have shared my personal calendar with my work account (by giving "edit" permissions to "work@work.com" through the settings in my personal account, right clicking on the calendar, and choosing Sharing, then accepting through my work account).
In my work Outlook I can now see both calendars.
I have then created a rule in my work Outlook for incoming messages, "which is a meeting invitation or update" to "move a copy to the specified folder" (where for specified I have selected the Personal Calendar). That rule is supposed to duplicate all calendar invites received to my personal calendar so I see them there (as my company doesn't allow to share my work calendar directly).
But it only shows them in my work Outlook. When I log in to my personal Outlook (whether from the web or on my personal computer) then they are not there. I thought that might be related to the fact that I haven't "accepted" them. I then tried in my work Outlook to "accept" the copied event and when I click "accept" it disappears (clarifying edit: the calendar entry itself disappears from the calendar, not just the message from the inbox, which is expected). When I re-run my rule, the event reappears (in the work Outlook) but it doesn't become visible in my personal Outlook, and accepting it deletes it again.
I tried creating an event manually in the Personal calendar from my Work Outlook. That works and it is immediately visible in my personal Outlook as well. But not for events that are copied via the rule I created. Any suggestions for how to get this to work would be appreciated.

In order to verify, did you share your personal calendar to your work account?
In this case, you will only see both calendars under your work account, but you will not be able to see your work calendar under your personal calendar.

I then tried in my work Outlook to "accept" the copied event and when I click "accept" it disappears.

It is a normal behavior that after you “Accept” or “Decline” the meeting, the invitation email will be missing in the Inbox folder.

Yes, shared personal with work so in my work Outlook I see both (not vice versa). That's what the rule is for.   I clarified the other issue, the email is expected to disappear from the inbox but in my case the calendar entry disappears from the calendar upon "accepting" it.  Expected behavior is it disappears when I "decline" it.
